# Unable to open Microsft Edge browser using selenium webdriver 2.53.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**I have written the below code to launch a web page in Microsoft Edge browser using selenium webdriver V 2.53.0:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver ed = new EdgeDriver();
ed.get("hhtp://www.google.com");
```

## **I'm getting the below error please help:**

```
[00:27:40.776] - Listening on http://localhost:17709/ 

[00:27:43.056] - Stopping server.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.29 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-MTDHI91G', ip: '10.0.0.112', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)    System.setProperty
    ("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    WebDriver ed = new EdgeDriver();
    ed.get("hhtp://www.google.com");
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:98)
at Selenium_WebDriver_Part1.Drivers.main(Drivers.java:58)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your browser version doesn't match with MS web driver. I had a similar issue. My browser version was 25.10586. Downloading Edge Windows/Microsoft Edge build 10586 from [Microsoft WebDriver Fall 2015 Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49962) fixed my issue.

Please also check [my answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162721/2583112) and [another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421592/2583112). It is suggesting that you should also check Capablities if you are on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ’hhtp’ should be replaced  with ’http’ in your URL?